# PHP script runs fine in firefox but appears to infinite loop in other browsers

Tags: php, python, firefox, google-chrome, infinite-loop

I have a PHP script on my site that is called using the jquery ajax function. Basically the user presses a button on my site and it sends an ajax call to this PHP script, which then uses proc_open to call a python script on my server. This all works fine when I test it in firefox, but when I test it in other browsers (chrome, safari, mobile safari) the script infinite loops. I have also tried calling the PHP script directly (by pasting the url into the browser) to check if its an infinite loop in my jquery and I get the same result (runs fine in ff, but infinite loops in all other browsers). From what I understand PHP code is executed server side and then the output is sent to the client browser so I cannot figure out why the script is only running in firefox. Ive also tried SSHing into my server and running the python script from command line and it runs fine, so I dont think its a problem with the python script.

Heres my php code:

```
<?php
require('../include/constants.php');
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])||!$_SESSION['logged_in'])
{
    header('location:../login.php');
}
$link = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
$q = "SELECT `cupiduser`,`cupidpass` FROM `users` WHERE `email`='".$_SESSION['email']."' LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysql_query($q);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$minage = $_GET['min'];
$maxage = $_GET['max'];
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w") // stderr is a file to write to
);
$cmd = 'python ~/data/users/demo2.py "'.$row['cupiduser'].'" "'.$row['cupidpass'].'" "'.$minage.'" "'.$maxage.'"';
$proc = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
if(is_resource($proc))
{
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    $count = fread($pipes[1], 512);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $exit = proc_close($proc);
}
echo trim($count);
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
ob_start();
?>
```

The python code is just running a few calculations and then at the end it returns a number like this:

```
print str(count)
```

Comment: What does Chrome say when you run it?  
Open the page in chrome and check the developer's console for errors

Comment: Problem is probable with the jquery. Could we have some of that code?

Comment: What do you mean by infinite loop? Do you mean that you repeatedly send ajax requests. Is your server hanging? Open up the network tab in  Chrome, if you haven't. It may be the js...

Comment: how can you get 'infinite loop' if there is no loops in your code =)? maybe you have redirect loop?

Comment: The problem isnt with the JQuery, I tried running the php script by going to the actual URL in all the browsers (bypassing the jquery) and got the same results.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to exit the script after sending the `location` header. See below.

```
<?php
require('../include/constants.php');
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])||!$_SESSION['logged_in'])
{
    header('location:../login.php');
    die(); // Exit script
}
```

***Note:** This may or may not be the root cause of the loop, but it **is** a problem that **must** be addressed in your code.*

### Why do I need to exit my script manually?

The `header()` call *only* sends a small string of text to the browser. However, PHP doesn't know the difference between `header('location:...')` and `header('foo:...')`... it only knows that the text sent to the `header()` function needs to be sent to the browser. Browsers may cut off the connection to the server immediately, or they may not--it's really up to them. So, if you don't want *any* code to be called after the `header('location:...')` call (which should always be the case, as it's unreliable to rely on the browser to keep the connection alive), then you should call `die()` or `exit()` (they're the same thing) immediately after sending the `location` header.

#### Example

```
<?php
header("location: http://www.example.com/");
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet the problem is situated under header() function. Try to run the script without this line of code.

Comment: You thinking session isn't logged in and attempting to do so, but getting redirected to itself?